# Problem with automount via sshfs

Tags: sshfs

I have this mount point configured in `/etc/stab`

```
sshfs#tomcat8@10.1.0.73:/opt/cache /opt/cache  fuse defaults,allow_other,nonempty,delay_connect  0 0
```

But seems it's not working as desired, as mount gets disconnect every now and then. Any ideas on which config file or log to look for possible diagnosis?

Reference OS:

```
uname -a
Linux tomcat-reports2 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

Comment: can you check if manually mount without fstab works, and still disconnect?

Comment: it doesn't disconnect immediately, so actually cannot guarantee if it'll stay mounted if I remount it manually. By your suggestion, should I comment it out of fstab, mount it manually and just wait to see what happens? The problem with that is eventual server reboots.

Comment: Yes, the best option to debug is comment fstab, and do it manually, eventually add verbose mode to sshfs by `-o sshfs_debug `

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is probably cut by a firewall due to inactivity (lack of TCP frames pertaining to the SSH connection). Try to enable keep-alive.

In your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, add:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ServerAliveInterval 30
ServerAliveCountMax 10
```

Comment: Sounds quite a good answer, as actually this setup is in AWS, between two different Availability Zones, where there obviously must exist a firewall in between. Will try it and let you know the results

Comment: added "metric" no monitor the results, will let you know what happens, thanks!